# Querydsl: How to write a "complex" query

Tags: java, querydsl

I'm trying to create an sql sentence using querydsl. What I'm trying to get is:

```
SELECT P.KEY, COUNT(P.VALUE)
 FROM RESOURCES R JOIN PROPERTIES P ON R.ID = P.ID
 WHERE P.KEY = "key" AND p.VALUE = "value"
 GROUP BY P.VALUE;
```

I've tried to write some querydsl code:

```
String s = queryFactory
    .query()
    .from(QResource.resource)
    .join(QProperty.property)
    .where(QResource.resource.properties.any().key.eq("key").and(QResource.resource.properties.any().value.eq("value")))
    .groupBy(QProperty.property.value)
    .select(QProperty.property.key, QProperty.property.value.count())
    .toString();
```

I'm guessing it can be simplified and by other hand I don't quite see if it's well querydsl-coded.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more simplified version would be:

```
QResource r = QResource.resource;
QProperty p = QProperty.property;
queryFactory
    .select(p.key, p.value.count())
    .from(r)
    .join(p).on(r.id.eq(p.id))
    .where(p.key.eq("key"), p.value.eq("value"))
    .groupBy(p.value)
    .fetchOne();
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @natros answer, Boolean operators can be used for 'and' logic

```
QResource r = QResource.resource;
QProperty p = QProperty.property;
queryFactory
    .select(p.key, p.value.count())
    .from(r)
    .join(p).on(r.id.eq(p.id))
    .where(p.key.eq("key").and(p.value.eq("value")))
    .groupBy(p.value)
    .fetchOne();
```

Boolean builders can be also used for complex logics

```
BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
builder.and(p.key.eq("key"));
builder.and(p.value.eq("value"));
queryFactory
        .select(p.key, p.value.count())
        .from(r)
        .join(p).on(r.id.eq(p.id))
        .where(builder)
        .groupBy(p.value)
        .fetchOne();
```